# HQL - Inner Join Error

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I want to select rows that have a distinct `fieldName`. And this query works just fine in PostgreSQL.

```
select f from FieldType as f inner join 
    (select fa.fieldName, min(fa.id) as id from FieldType fa group by fa.fieldName)
    as f1 on f.fieldName =:f1.fieldName and f.id =:f1.id
```

But I can't make this query to work in `Java` using `HQL`. I always keep getting this error

> **org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: (**

Removing paranthesis just moves error to the next character. How can I fix this? I'm open to any suggestions.

Comment: HQL and SQL are different languages. You can't pass a SQL query to a method expecting a HQL query, just like you can't pass C++ code to a Java compiler.

Comment: this is more like a native query , use the native query option of hibernate

Comment: I'm not sure what it doesn't like about the subquery, but I'm pretty sure it won't be happy about =:, as : designates a parameter you have to set from outside, and joining on a set parameter makes no sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you would have to perform a sort of correlated query instead in order to take advantage HQL:

```
select f from FieldType as f 
where (f.fieldName, f.id) in 
   (select fa.fieldName, min(fa.id) as id 
    from FieldType fa
    group by fa.fieldName)
```